# AWS email "You are approaching your AWS Free Tier limit" but not

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

AWS sent this email:

[image]

Basically it says that i am using 1 cloudwatch alarm, and the forecasted is 31.
The fact is that currently i am not using any AWS services, in fact if i go to cloudwatch of each region this is the output:

[image]

What else should I check?
Note the billing is at 0$ of course

Comment: I think since we are talking about cloudwatch is perfectly in topic here, and it can interest many software developers

Comment: my bad, sorry about that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lots of people go these emails yesterday. A few have opened up tickets for clarification, and I suspect there will be a followup email in the near future:

https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/7ndvli/anybody_get_spurious_aws_budgets_alarms_early_on/

Answer (score 4):

I got a similar message, except I have 18 real alarms, and it is forecasting I will use 136! I think the forecasting algorithm is broken. I see the same type of forecasting "errors" on our production site. There they seem calculate your spend average in the past days, and multiply it by the days in month. This can leads to wildly inflated forecasts, especially if you paid for IR upfront early in the month.

I would ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

**Amazon Official Reply to the Emails**

> Hello,
>
> [Deleted]
>
> You can access your AWS account to review your service usage and any associated charges related to that usage. Note that the usage and billing data you see in your AWS account are correct. For more information on AWS Free Tier please visit https://aws.amazon.com/free/ .
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused.
>
> Sincerely, Amazon Web Services

Yup, Amazon made a mistake with their CloudWatch services. I too got that email.

Answer (score -1):

Not to worry at all, actually AWS forecasted this result on the basis of your last month usage and if you continue to use this service then you might cross the free tier limit.